# Change an double type value from a variable to String/text output in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, currency

I have a double type value that I call from another class named Account, and this value holds the `balance`, of a user. Everytime a user click a button, I want to put it on display. Something like this :

[image]

The value (taken from class Account) should be located and presented below `Your current balance(RM):`. But when I use the code below here, it won't even run the code.

```
Label balanceInfo = new Label("Your current balance (RM) :"+Double.toString(user[currentIndex].getBalance()));
```

The code only runs when I delete this part of the line : `+Double.toString(user[currentIndex].getBalance())` 
I have also tried using `+user[currentIndex].getBalance()` , and the code won't run.

So how do I make it so that it can show the value like `290.00` (double type) below the Label text `Your current balance(RM):` ?

Comment: Do not use `double` for currency - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/2670892)

Answer (score 3):

If `user.getBalance()` returns a primitive `double` or a `Double`, then the following should work :

```
Label balanceInfo = new Label("Your current balance (RM) :" + user[currentIndex].getBalance());
```

---

As pointed out in the comment, [you should not use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) `double` to store a currency, but for example a `BigDecimal`. With `BigDecimal` the code above will still work, or to format really as a currency:

```
Label balanceInfo = new Label("Your current balance (RM) :" + 
    NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(user[currentIndex].getBalance()));
```

**Example:**

```
BigDecimal money = new BigDecimal(2345.856);
Label label = new Label("Your balance: " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(money));
```

will produce a `Label` like:

[image]

Comment: I never knew about this before. Does that mean I have to change my Account class data type (since the balance is taken from that class), or just in this GUI class? Thanks again.

Comment: As a general design rule, you should not store any data in the view, so yes, the Account data class should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use DecimalFormat class.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.print(df.format(user[currentIndex].getBalance()));
```